# Selected files to upload vanish when form is invalid on submission

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

When a user selects a file to upload along with it and submits an invalid form, the file they selected disappears, while the remainder of the form remains intact. Is there a way to make it so that the selected file doesn't disappear upon an invalid submission?

I should include that I didn't make a ViewModel for this. They're two different models (the form/fields themselves, and the document info) being smushed together. Would making a ViewModel of the form with the document included in it prevent this from happening? (If so, I'd have to refactor most of my code unfortunately, which isn't the best option right now)

I was also considering throwing in unobtrusive validation via JS to bypass this, but I wanted to see some other potential solutions I could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other form controls, you cannot set the value for a `<input type="file" />` in the controller. If you could it would be a major security issue (imagine navigating to a site that included hundreds of hidden file inputs with say "C:/Password.doc" - it would download files from your device without your knowledge).

If you need to return the view because the model is invalid, then the user needs to either re-select the file, or you need to save the file before returning the view (perhaps to a temporary location). You could then return the name and path of that file so that it could be displayed in the view to indicate that it has been uploaded (and perhaps an associated delete button so the user could delete it if they changed their mind.

Having a view model with properties for `HttpPostedFileBase` and the file name and its temporary path would make handling this easier.

Comment: The security aspect was my biggest thought. I guess I might try the HttpPostedFileBase solution though--I think we have some code I can work off from...